# MySQL - Getting the top-level parent id in a hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here's my table structure...

TABLE : **position_hierarchy_level**

```
id parent_position_id position_id
 1 1                  2
 2 2                  3
 3 3                  4
 4 4                  5
 5 5                  6
 6 6                  7
 7 7                  8
 8 8                  9
 9 9                  10
 10 10                11
 11 11                12
 12 12                13
 13 13                14
 14 14                15
```

My query for getting the `parent_position_id` of a certain `position_id` is:

```
select `parent_position_id` from `position_hierarchy_level` where position_id= 15;
```

But how can I get the top-most parent of a certain `position_id`? For example, the top-most `parent_position_id` of `position_id` 15 would be `1`.

Is there a convenient way to get this value using a single query? Or do I need to create a loop in PHP?

Comment: I don't see any row with `id = 15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database structure wouldnt let you do it unless there are 15 or more joins. You are using *Adjacency list model*.  Try using [*The nested set model*](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Here is [an example](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) with php

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getTopParentPositionId(positionId INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE y INT;
    SET x = positionId;
    sloop:LOOP
        SET y = NULL;
        SELECT parent_position_id INTO y FROM position_hierarchy_level WHERE position_id = x;
        IF y IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE sloop;
        END IF;  
        SET x = y;
        ITERATE sloop;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN x;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then:

```
SELECT getTopParentPositionId( 5 );
```

Obviously, [you are not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031469/how-to-properly-loop-in-a-stored-function-on-mysql) who looked into thoose kind of solution :)

Comment: its working great, a very good mysql function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same problem:
[Recursive PHP function for adjacency-list display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242276/recursive-php-function-for-adjacency-list-display)

Using a single query with mysql could be kind of different. Maybe you could solve this with a stored procedure.

Comment: I just need the top most parent

Comment: select id, parent_position_id, position_id from position_hierarchy_level where parent_position_id=min(parent_position_id)  - or didnt i understand the problem?

Comment: better: select id, position_id from position_hierarchy_level order by parent_position_id limit 1

Comment: i want to get the **parent_position_id** using a certain **position_id** it should reiterate in each record.

Comment: @Broncko, he need a tree data to get the top-most parent id.

Comment: Then you should think about using a nested set. It definitely works better with deep hierarchical structures. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_Sets

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly and you want to highest position_id to have 1 for parent_position_id  and so on ...

1 . SET parent_position_id to auto increment

2 . select position_id from table order by position_id desc and put them in a array

3 . truncate table

4 . insert array to table

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a convenient way to get it using a single query?

I think NO, take look [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) for Hierarchical queries in MySQL

> do I need to create a loop statement in PHP?

I think YES.

Answer (score 1):

With this table structure the best option you have is a loop in php end of things.

If the table structure is something you can freely change (in case if project isn't *live* already), you might want to look into structure called `Closure Tables`. You can find a simple example of how the are used/setup in [this article](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html).

In any case, you should be able to find a lot more on the subject in the [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book.